# Int to bytes and backwards

Tags: c++, binary, byte

Im saving game map in binary format to the file. The general structure of file is:

- (4byte) width
- (4byte) height
- width * height:

  - (1byte) tile
- width * height:

  - (4byte) data

To reduce size of file, I decided to save everything in chars, since I know exact sizes of numbers I want to read. I made 2 functions, getByte and makeInt:

```
unsigned char getByte(int src, short int c) //get byte number c from src
{
    return ((char*)(&src))[c];
}

int makeInt(char src[4]) //build int from src
{
    int r=0;
    for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        r+=(r<<8)+((unsigned char*)(src))[i];
    return r;
}
```

Here is how I save and load my map:

```
void Map::save(const char *fname)
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open(fname,fstream::out | fstream::binary);

    for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        f.put(getByte(W,i));
    for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        f.put(getByte(H,i));

    for (int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++)
            f.put(tiles[i][j]);

    for (int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++)
            for (int k=3; k>=0; k--)
                f.put(getByte(data[i][j],k));

    f.close();
}

void Map::load(const char *fname)
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open(fname,fstream::in | fstream::binary);

    char bytes[4];

    for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        f.get(bytes[i]);    
    W=makeInt(bytes);

    for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        f.get(bytes[i]);
    H=makeInt(bytes);

    for (int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++)
            f.get(tiles[i][j]);

    for (int i=0; i<W; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++)
        {
            for (int k=3; k>=0; k--)
                f.get(bytes[k]);
            data[i][j]=makeInt(bytes);
        }

    f.close();
}
```

Tiles (char) are saved and loaded well, everything is okay. But the int's are not. Due to weird bug, when I save 256, I load 257. Instead of expected 512, I read 514. I don't want to make it dirty way (r-=r/256)... I also had some problems with signs, and that's probably why this all happens. Before adding some unsigned casts, after 127 was -127, -126, -125, and so on. If this helps here is the map class:

```
class Map
{
    public:
        int W;
        int H;

        char tiles[MW][MH]; //MW and MH are macros, now they are 64.
        int data[MW][MH];

        void save(const char *fname);
        void load(const char *fname);

    /* moar code */
};
```

I tested it by generating map with this pattern:

```
for (int i=0; i<64; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<64; j++)
        map.data[i][j]=(i*64+j);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r+=(r<<8)+((unsigned char*)(src))[i];` should be `r=(r<<8)+((unsigned char*)(src))[i];`

Now, my general concern is that maybe you shouldn't worry too much about saving a byte here or there. If you really want to save space, use some proper compression technique - huffman coding, byte pair, or something like that.

Are you sure you save any space over using f.write() and f.read() - I'm pretty sure your code would be much simpler - and unless you are intending to store the files on one machine, ship them across to another that has a different byte order, and then load them in the code there, it's a lot of extra work to store a byte at a time. Although I'm sure it's a good learning exercise. At least writing a function to store one int at a time would probably help a great deal to clean up the code.

Comment: Both answers were posted at same time, I gonna accept yours, becouse I like the idea of compression :) also, you have less reputation that Matthew.

Comment: I should thank you :D Im working on this thing for 2 hours now =) (I have never ever before tried do do anything on bytes/bits itself)

Comment: I just added some more commentary to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect (function makeInt(char[4])):

```
r+=(r<<8)+((unsigned char*)(src))[i];
```

You want `r = r<<8 + ...`.  As it is, you're accumulating the value more than once.